# Random key presses in RDP connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

There are several questions on superuser about keys jamming in an rdp session, but this question is not a duplicate, at least insofar as I've found.

I'm using a PC running Windows 7 over an rdp connection, both from another Win7 machine as well as from a Mac, running OS X 10.9.3, using Microsoft's rdp client. The problem is that intermittently, at seemingly random intervals a window with the title "Change document" pops up, with the icons of the currently running programs in it. This is very annoying, as the window steals focus. Also there are some other random key presses happening, as my code editor sometimes switches tabs (alt+arrow key). These anomalies occur even when the rdp client doesn't have focus, and thus shouldn't receive any actual input.

These problems never occur when using the server directly. All machines are in the same lan and communicating with local ips. Any ideas what might be the cause, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out: the "random" key presses weren't in fact so random, but they were leaking from the user using the server locally via Logitech's MX5500 mouse & keyboard helper app, that was starting up automatically for all users. Shutting down the remote users instance stopped the leakage.